# Programming HTTP Request in Android

Tags: android, httprequest

Using WireShark, I know that the Form Item have a 'Key' / 'Value' pair that is used to search for a serial number. For example, key=vsn, serial=p2x242334.

How could I program an http request for this and get back the content to work with?

I am hoping to automate a very tedious process of people looking one serial at a time using a webform to see if a log was created for one of their customers.

General guidelines, and I'll figure it out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 List<NameValuePair> f = new List<NameValuePair>();
 f.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", "vsn"));
 HttpPost pr = new HttpPost(TheURL);
 pr.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(f, "UTF-8"));
 HttpResponse Resp = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(pr);
```

Just don't do it on the main thread, or it'll exception on Android 3+.

Comment: Hi Seva, and thank you for your answer! Okay, so I'm to work on that. What a great community this place is. Thanks again.

Comment: We say thanks here by upvoting and/or accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Despite the many examples and "tutorials" on the web showing the use of too-low-level things like HTTPUrlConnection, the easiest way by far to do web requests (REST or otherwise) is the Retrofit library.

There are many good Retrofit tutorials available on the web,
but basically, you'll create an interface that describes the requests that you want to make, and then Retrofit will generate an implementation.

Your interface will look something like this:

```
public interface Api {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @Post(“/search”)
    User search(@Field String key, @Field String serial);
}
```

And then you can use the method implemented by retrofit to make an asynchronous request, something like this:

```
RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint("http://example.com")
                .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient));

RestAdapter restAdapter = builder.build();

Api apiClient = restAdapter.create(Api.class);

apiClient.search("vsn", "p2x242334", new Callback<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Response response) {
                // use the response
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                // handle the error
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi GreyBeardedGeek, and thanks for the answer. May i ask, what benefits do you see in using this library? I'll google it now of course. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: It's a very mature library that works extremely well, and makes asynchronous  http calls very easy to do. You wind up writing/maintaining very little code.